# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged when trying to merge branch

Tags: git, heroku

I have a branch that I've been using to deploy to Heroku and I want to merge it with the origin so that I can just deploy origin. But when I try i get this error:

> Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged

Comment: That message (your branch(es) have diverged) is not an *error*, it's just information. Heroku is full of oddities though and as I am not a Heroku user I hesitate to make any suggestions here.

Answer (score 0):

The message you see means that your local branch (very likely `master`) and the remote one `origin/master` are no longer synchronized (or one being ahead of the other by a bunch of commits) but are now forking and following each their own direction, even if they have a common parent in a recent past.

This actually happens if:

1. You or someone pushed new commits on both side (local and remote) since the time you cloned your repository. In this case, you want to fetch/pull the remote commits first, and you may need to merge them, resolving conflicts if there's some ;
2. Someone did a `reset --hard` then `push -f` on the remote branch to cancel some stuff and rewrite history. In this case, you'll need to rebase your branch onto the new tip.

Comment: If I rebase, will the branch merge with the master?